# SQL Where statement with case doesn't print any record

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a SQL query which has a Where statement. In that Where statement, I want to check a clause. The query is shown below:

```
select * 
from new_payment
where  new_totalprofit>@totalprofit 
  and (RTRIM(LTRIM(left(P.new_name ,(CHARINDEX('-',P.new_name)-1)))) =
         case 
            when @paymenttype<>'All' 
            then @paymenttype end)
```

I checked that there are existing records in that query but no records are showing. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the data inside that table? What is the value supplied to `@paymenttype`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CASE` expression will be returning `NULL` if `@paymentType` is equal to `All`, and so you'll get no results. You don't need a `CASE` expression:

```
select * from new_payment
 where  new_totalprofit>@totalprofit and
 (
    @paymenttype='All' or
    (RTRIM(LTRIM(left(P.new_name ,(CHARINDEX('-',P.new_name)-1)))) =
    @paymenttype)
 )
```

Comment: there is two type of record in new_paymenttype column.these are 'Credit Card' and 'Miles Point' when @payment='all' i want to make it doesn't check anything.

Comment: And do you think that the query I've shown above doesn't meet that requirement? If not, why?

Comment: Oh sorry. Now i got your code.you are avoiding returning null.@paymenttype='All'clause returning true or false for nothing so that helps on my purpose